# Update probabilities from a classifier with a priori probabilties

Tags: probability, predictive-models

I am trying to build a model to correct the class probability given by a classifier with a priori probabilities. Here are the probabilities that I have for that model:

- predicted probabilities from the classifier
- a priori probabilities
- probability of a class

Any suggestion?

Comment: what are the questions you hope to answer based on your data? what is the data you would like to model? what is the model you thought of?